# Issue with SSL and detecting the desired protocol

Tags: curl, ssl, opera

I have this strange issue with how ssl works on one of our internal services. It uses SSL and it has some strange problem that with `curl` or Opera browser you can't get a response from it. But if, for curl, you point what protocol it should use: `curl --sslv3` it will work.

I tried to google I swear, but no results at all.

You can access the server using `https://einstein.namshi.net/` - it works in Chrome, it should redirect you to the authentication page if everything is fine, but with curl you'll get `empty reply`.

Answer (score 1):

This is very strange.
The TLS handshake is successful but then the connection is abruptly closed by the server, without a proper SSL shutdown. This looks for me like a problem at the server side or with some middleware in-between (firewall, load balancer), please check the logs there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is definetly a server-side problem, I just thought maybe people aware of it and faced it already